# "lvmetad is not active yet" when using a GPU

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I recently acquired an R910 Dell server which I refurbished as a workstation and installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. Since the built in GPU can barely run the GUI, I put in a GPU I had lying around, which worked like a charm. I then upgraded to 16.04, and now Ubuntu refuses to boot and gives the "lvmetad is not active yet"-error. Removing the GPU solves the problem, but the GUI is obviously then correspondingly slow. I don't know what is causing that and I cant see why lvm has anything to do with the GPU?

Any ideas?

EDIT: the GPUs tried so far are an ASUS EN8600GT and an ATI FireGL V5200. The V5200 worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04. It seems that AMD dropped support for the V5200 card and as far as I could gather, the pre-installed ubuntu drivers are supposed to do the trick instead? (evidently not)

EDIT2: Ubuntu now refuses to login by immediately sending me back to the login screen after login. I thinking the easiest solution might to roll back to 14.04.

Comment: I don't think that the lvmetad and the gpu are related. I think the lvmetad is a normal message, and the gpu is the boot problem. Did you install a new driver for the gpu when you upgraded to 16.04?

Comment: Indeed. Please edit and add the information regarding the new hardware. The message is unrelated and probably was there all along but you just couldn't see it. When booting normally the "quiet splash" default makes those messages not visible. But when the video driver isn't loading for whatever reason then you see those messages.